# Folder Paths with Spaces

Tags: c#, filepath

I need to hardcode a file path, but the path contains spaces, so it is not being interpreted properly.  I haven't found a workaround that worked :(  This is the filepath I need to use but the path is broken at the first space so it reads NetBrain\Personnel\Mangers\Daily which is invalid so it throws an error

```
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)oXL.Workbooks.Open("\\\\NetBrain\\Personnel\\Managers\\Daily And Weekly Logs\\Mitchell.xls");
```

Comment: Try using `@"Folder path"`

Comment: Where (and how) are you using the path?

Comment: please post the complete code

Comment: You could try adding the " character at the start and the end of the path like \"\\\\NetBrain\\Personnel\\Managers\\Daily And Weekly Logs\\\"

Comment: What error does it throw? And what is this related to anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to avoid spaces (because even in this millennium they cause problems in unexpected places), or to quote the names so that they are treated as a single path instead of two or more fragments.

To quote a file path you just need to add double quotes `"`, like this:

```
path = "\"" + path + "\"";
```

Take care not to quote a path that is already quoted.

Most places where you pass a path will not needed the quoted path - it's usually only if a path is passed through a command line interface that it will require quoting.

This may or may not work with the specific Excel example that you posted, as it how it works all depends on how Excel handles the path internally.

Comment: Are those double quotes so it reads "\"" at the front and "\"" at the end?

Comment: Yes, "\"" is doublequote, backslash, doublequote, doublequote. (Sorry, had formatting problems on my phone so had to switch to my laptop to edit the answer and get the formatting right!)

Answer (score 0):

Define it in a constant or static variable

```
const String myPath = @"\\NetBrain\Personnel\Managers\Daily And Weekly Logs\Mitchell.xls"

oWB = (Excel._Workbook)oXL.Workbooks.Open(myPath)
```

Adding second option with your comment update

Try

```
const String myPath = @"\\NetBrain\Personnel\Managers\Daily And Weekly Logs\Mitchell.xls"

Uri u = new Uri(myPath);    
oWB = (Excel._Workbook)oXL.Workbooks.Open(u.AbsoluteUri);
```

Comment: Defining it as a const String myPath is still causing the same issue.

Comment: I send this as a hyperlink and when the receiver gets the hyperlink it looks like this    \\NetBrain\Personnel\Managers\Daily (hyperlink ends there) And Weekly Logs\Mitchell.xls

Comment: what do you mean by hyperlink receiver?  How is this used?  It may be that you need to encode it for use with the web.  I dont think you have given use all the details of how this is being sent, received and used.